# After getting a PhD at a low-ranked university, would it be harder to get a job at a high-ranked university?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, computer-science

In more detail, let's say I get a PhD degree at a university which is ranked 51-100, according to QS ranking system. Is it possible for me to get a job at higher ranked university, like 1-50 ?
Let's say without extraordinary publication record, which I believe the answer would be possible..

Comment: No matter where your Phd is from, without an extraordinary publication record you will not get a tenure track job at a high ranked university.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving from a Ph.D. at a mid-ranked institution to a postdoc at a high-ranked institutions happens very frequently.  The easiest path for this is to have solid publications (extraordinary is not necessary) and a good relationship with both your Ph.D. advisor and the supervisor you do the postdoc with.

One of the important factors enabling this is that a strict ranking of Ph.D. programs does not make much sense once you get above a certain base level of quality.  Beyond that point, every program is extremely heterogeneous based on the particular professor.  Absolutely world class professors are often at "mid-ranked" universities, and people *in their particular subfield* will know it, and consider that university "elite" *in their particular subfield*.  It's just that you can't obtain this information from US News or other "generic" rankings.

An example: US News currently gives the [University of Massachusetts, Amherst](http://www.umass.edu/), a rank of [#60 in the US as an Engineering grad school and #76 overall](http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges/umass-amherst-2221), but they have an extremely strong artificial intelligence group that practically dominates in some subfields.